# Remove Disabled users in a CVS file from all Office 365 Groups that appear on the admin portal

Tags: powershell, office365

I am Trying to Remove all users who are in a csv file from all the groups they are showing up under in the Office 365 admin portal, The code bellow doesn't seem to delete all the groups and still has some left under their name. Is there something I am missing?

```
Write-Host "Fetching the CSV..."
       $file = "X:\1Onboarding.TerminationCSV\DisabledUsers.csv"
        Write-Host "Importing from $file..."
    
        $csv = Import-Csv $file
    
        if ($csv -eq $null)
        { Write-Host "No CSV file found. exiting script in 3 seconds"
          #Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
          Exit }
    
    #Credentials
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString “*Hidden*” -AsPlainText -Force
    $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“*hidden*”, $password)
    
    #Connect to AzureAD
    Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred
     
    #Get all Azure AD Unified Groups
    $AADGroups = Get-AzureADMSGroup -All:$true
    
    foreach ($member in  $csv) #loop through csv for users--------------------
    {
    
    $username= $member.username
    
    Write-Output "username is $username"
    #Get the Azure AD User
    $AADUser  = Get-ADUser -filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username}
    
    $groupCount = 0
    
    ForEach ($Group in $AADGroups)
    {
        $GroupMembers = (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group.id).UserPrincipalName
        If ($GroupMembers -contains $UserUPN)
        {
        Write-Output "$username is in $($Group.DisplayName)"
         #Remove user from Group
            try { Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $Group.Id -MemberId $AADUser.ObjectId }
                catch { "$($Group.DisplayName) is not an azure group" }
            try {Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Group.Id -Member $AADUser.ObjectId -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -Confirm:$false }
                catch { "$($Group.DisplayName) is not a distribution group" }
            $groupCount +=1
        }
    }
    
    Write-Output "$AADUser is in $groupCount groups"
    }
```

Comment: I would have to test this but I'm almost certain that the `ObjectID` of an AD OnPrem user is different than the `ObjectID` of this same user in Azure AD. Instead of searching for your user in AD OnPrem you should search for it on Azure (change `$AADUser` var for `Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $userName`)

Comment: In fact, there is no such attribute as `ObjectID` in AD On Prem (you have `GUID` and `SID`). Another thing I'm seeing is that there is no reference as to how `$userUPN` is being generated.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I meant to change the $userUPN to $username. also I removed the line ( $AADUser  = Get-ADUser -filter {sAMAccountName -eq $username})  and added :Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $userName. but unfortunately, it is taking longer than expected to remove one single group.

Comment: I can help you making the script a bit more efficient, I can see why it is taking so long but first of all, do you see the `$AADUser` being populated now after changing to `Get-AzureADUser`?

Comment: What happens if you try `Remove-AzureADGroupMember` manually with one `objectID` and `groupID`. Do you see the user being removed from the group?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I think it is populated the line of code looks like this :
    $AADUser = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $userName

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon let me try that and see I'm not really sure how to do it manually since I don't know the detail of the groups like the ID and such

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon it is still not doing anything, taking a long time to run as im typing this its still at the first line username is " username"

Answer (score 0):

See, this should be more efficient than bringing all existing Azure AD Groups.

- First, search for the user provided in the CSV on Azure AD
- If the user exist, get it's membership. Else, write a warning
- Loop over the AADuser's membership removing it from all of them

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

#Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred
    
foreach ($member in  $csv) #loop through csv for users
{
    $AADUser = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $member.userName

    if($AADUser)
    {
        $membership = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $AADUser.ObjectID

        foreach($group in $membership)
        {
            try
            {
                Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectID -MemberId $AADUser.ObjectID
                Write-Output "Successfully removed {0} from {1}" -f $AADUser.userPrincipalName,$group.displayName
            }
            catch
            {
                Write-Warning "Failed to remove {0} from {1} with the following error:`n$_" -f $AADUser.userPrincipalName,$group.DisplayName
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "{0} could not be found on Azure AD" -f $member.userName
    }
}
```